# WCF listenBacklog and maxConnections can't be set higher than 10. Why not?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

My service works great under low load.  But under high load I start to get connection errors.

I know about other settings but I am trying to change the listenBacklog parameter in particular for my TCP Buffered binding.

If I set listenBacklog="10" I am able to telnet into the port where my WCF service is running.

If I change listenBacklog to anything higher than 10 it will not let me telnet into my service when it is running.

No errors seem to be thrown.

What can I do?
I get the same problem when I change my maxConnections away from 10.  All other properties of the binding I can set higher without a problem.

Here is what my binding looks like:

```
 <bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
<binding name="NetTcpBinding_IMyService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
  openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
  transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
  hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
  maxBufferSize="1048576" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="1048576">
  <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
    maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
  <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
    enabled="false" />
  <security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign">
    </transport>
    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
  </security>
</binding>
...
```

I really need to increase the values of maxConnections and listenBacklog

Comment: Great first question. Keep it up. ... I see that your clientCredentialType is set to Windows. I'm not sure if there is a connection but it makes think: Is it possible that you also have a maximum 10 connection limit set on the physical folder(s) that host(s) your application? Check on that. This might be a platform-level issue rather than a logical WCF issue.

Comment: What machine and OS are you running this on?? I vaguely recall certain Windows versions having a "10 clients max" limitation built right into Windows - maybe that's your problem here: Windows allows you to 10 callers and then shuts the doors... if you're running this on XP or something: try it on a Windows Server version

Answer (score 6):

If you're running on a Win2000, XP, Vista or Win7 machine, then the OS is limiting you to 10 concurrent TCP connections. Try running on a Windows Server machine to confirm.

Comment: Is there a way to change the OS value? I have the same issue under Win7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true. I also get the same results in Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: [rant]How can I benchmark my application to make sure it performs well under load when some moron arbitrarily decides that I can only have 10 TCP connections? I've wasted hours fiddling with  MaxConcurrentXXX, to finally discover that it's an OS limitation. An eternal pox on the people that imposed this brain-dead limitation. @MS Nobody with half a brain is going to cheat your licences by running a public Netflix server on Windows 7 home edition. That there are limits, fine, but reasonable ones, please[/rant]

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly a throttling issue. Try specifying non-default values for the service throttling behavior values. [See this page for some guidance](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/752d64d5-e20f-4149-a263-631c329d1335).

Answer (score -2):

Try to remove all references to HTTP bindings and MEX.